# C# How to return a value between 2 .cs files

Tags: c#, return

So i am trying to return the discount amount between 2 .cs files into the main and print out the amount there instead of doing it on the second class. I am pretty new at this and i need help

*code is not yet complete*

MAIN

```
using System;

    namespace CalcDiscount
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter price");
                double input = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();
                myCalculator.Calculation(input);

                  Console.WriteLine("Enter discount");
                input = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

SECOND FILE 
calculator.cs

```
using System;

    namespace CalcDiscount
    {
        public class Calculator
        {
            public void Calculation(double input)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your entered the number: " + input);
                int i = 1;
                if (input != 0)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine(input + " x " + i + " = " + input * i);

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: so do you want to return some value from `Calculation()` function?

Comment: i am pretty new at this. but yeah i need to return the result of a calculation and then print it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the method Calculation in your Calculator class, from void to double. The method will calculate the result and return it to the main function, where it will be printed.

Calculation method:

```
public double Calculation(double input1, double input2)
{
      return (input1 * input2);
}
```

Main:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter first input");
 double input1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.WriteLine("Enter second input");
 double input2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();
 double result = myCalculator.Calculation(input1, input2);
 Console.WriteLine("result = " + result);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was trying something like result = input1 * input2;
(new line) return result;

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Calculator
    {
        public double Calculation(double input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your entered the number: " + input);
            int i = 1;
            double result = 0;
            if (input != 0)
            {
                result = i * input;

            }

            return result;

        }
    }
```

I made here a few changes

1. changed the return type to double (because you send double so it logical to return the same type but not necessary
2. add a `result` variable to return the result
3. did the calculation ( `result = i * input`)
4. return the `result`

note that if i == 0 the result will be 0, because `result` is initialized to zero, but can apply any logic that you want

and in your `Main` i read the result from the function and output it to the `Console`

```
double result = myCalculator.Calculation(input);
Console.WriteLine("caculcation result is" + result);
```